# Edit-text with Drop-down box in HTML5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want edit text with a drop down box along with custom scrollbar so end user can add data explicitly or can add from drop down box. The final entered value by end user should be saved.I want this in UI development preferably **angular js**.

Comment: Ok. What have you tried? What blocked you? Because we won't simply do this for you.

Comment: How much are you paying?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Well from what i understood , you need a text input as well as a dropdown input together.

To be frank , this is quite easy and i dont understand what caught you up in this.

So here is the code:

```html
<input type="text"/>
<select style="width:20px;">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="banana">Banana</option>
<option value="apple">Apple</option>
<option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

Check out the jsfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kna3fj5t/